# Open Office 1.1.4 Export to PDF with background images using java

Tags: java, pdf, openoffice.org

I have a problem that needs solving where we use OpenOffice 1.1.4 templated reports and programmatically export them to PDF. 
The team who create the templates have recently changed the header image and some images in a table to background images (before they were just inserted) since this change the current program is not creating the PDFs with the images. We can export from OpenOffice manually and the images are included. Can anyone help with a change I may need to make to get these background images included please?

The current code:

```
private void print(XInterface xComponent,
        PrintRequestDTO printReq, File sourceFile,
        Vector<String> pages) throws java.lang.Exception {

    String pageRange;

    // XXX create the PDF via OOo export facility
    com.sun.star.frame.XStorable pdfCreator = (com.sun.star.frame.XStorable) UnoRuntime
            .queryInterface(
                    com.sun.star.frame.XStorable.class,
                    xComponent);

    PropertyValue[] outputOpts = new PropertyValue[2];

    outputOpts[0] = new PropertyValue();
    outputOpts[0].Name = "CompressionMode";
    outputOpts[0].Value = "1"; // XXX Change this perhaps?

    outputOpts[1] = new PropertyValue();
    outputOpts[1].Name = "PageRange";

    if (printReq.getPageRange() == null) {

        pageRange = "1-";

    }
    else {

        if (printReq.getPageRange().length() > 0) {

            pageRange = printReq.getPageRange();

        }
        else {

            pageRange = "1-";

        }

    }

    log.debug("Print Instruction - page range = "
            + pageRange);

    PropertyValue[] filterOpts = new PropertyValue[3];

    filterOpts[0] = new PropertyValue();
    filterOpts[0].Name = "FilterName";
    filterOpts[0].Value = "writer_pdf_Export"; // MS Word 97

    filterOpts[1] = new PropertyValue();
    filterOpts[1].Name = "Overwrite";
    filterOpts[1].Value = new Boolean(true);

    filterOpts[2] = new PropertyValue();
    filterOpts[2].Name = "FilterData";
    filterOpts[2].Value = outputOpts;

    if (pages.size() == 0) { // ie no forced page breaks
        // set page range
        outputOpts[1].Value = pageRange;
        filterOpts[2] = new PropertyValue();
        filterOpts[2].Name = "FilterData";
        filterOpts[2].Value = outputOpts;

        File outputFile = new File(
                sourceFile.getParent(),
                printReq.getOutputFileName()
                        + ".pdf");

        StringBuffer sPDFUrl = new StringBuffer(
                "file:///");
        sPDFUrl.append(outputFile.getCanonicalPath()
                .replace('\\', '/'));

        log.debug("PDF file = " + sPDFUrl.toString());

        if (pdfCreator != null) {

            sleep();
            pdfCreator.storeToURL(sPDFUrl.toString(),
                    filterOpts);

        }
    }
    else if (pages.size() > 1) {
        throw new PrintDocumentException(
                "Only one forced split catered for currently");
    }
    else { // a forced split exists.
        log.debug("Page break found in "
                + (String) pages.firstElement());
        String[] newPageRanges = calculatePageRanges(
                (String) pages.firstElement(), pageRange);

        int rangeCount = newPageRanges.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < rangeCount; i++) {
            outputOpts[1].Value = newPageRanges[i];
            log.debug("page range = " + newPageRanges[i]);
            filterOpts[2] = new PropertyValue();
            filterOpts[2].Name = "FilterData";
            filterOpts[2].Value = outputOpts;
            String fileExtension = (i == 0 && rangeCount > 1) ? "__Summary.pdf"
                    : ".pdf";
            File outputFile = new File(
                    sourceFile.getParent(),
                    printReq.getOutputFileName()
                            + fileExtension);

            StringBuffer sPDFUrl = new StringBuffer(
                    "file:///");
            sPDFUrl.append(outputFile.getCanonicalPath()
                    .replace('\\', '/'));
            log.debug("PDF file = " + sPDFUrl.toString());

            if (pdfCreator != null) {
                log.debug("about to create the PDF file");
                sleep();
                pdfCreator.storeToURL(
                        sPDFUrl.toString(), filterOpts);
                log.debug("done");
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When your application runs can you *see* the file loaded in Open Office before the save to PDF?  You may need to set the visibility on loading the document.  If so, are the images visible?

Comment: No the file is hidden. I did think that and tried to make it visible but I could not get it to do so. If you can help me to make it open viewable i'd appreciate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad that suggestion of making the document visible helped.  Since it has ALSO fixed the problem you have a timing/threading issue.  I suspect you'll find that another dodgy option of doing a sleep before executing the save to PDF will also allow the images to appear.  Neither of these solutions is good.

Most likley best fix is to upgrade to a newer version of Open Office (the API calls you have should still work).  Another option would be to try to call the API to ask the document to refresh itself.

Answer (score 0):

After finding the correct property I was able to open the file with the hidden property set to false, this meant when the file was exported to PDF it included the background images. Its a shame I could not find another solultion that kept the file hidden but at least its working.